# Rails error in inline edit using gem 'best_in_place'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying use gem 'best_in_place' in table edit,  but having error while using it
in controller only index method for display all users details from db.

Error: `undefined method` name' for "Rohit":String`

Code used:

```
      <% @user_record.each do |record| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= best_in_place record.name, :name %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

controller Code:

```
    def index
      @user_record = MUser.search(params[:name],params[:gender])
    end
    
    def create
    end
```

Comment: We need a bit more context here. Where does `record` come from becuase right now it is a `String` but you seem to be implying that it should be a `MUser`? Please post the revelant portions of code around this `<td><%= best_in_place record.name, :name %></td>` in which the local variable `record` is declared

Comment: @engineersmnky Sir, please check, i have update table body data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I see from the [docs](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#best_in_place) the first argument you pass to the method `best_in_place` should be an object `record` and the second - a field you need to edit with this gem, in your case it is `name`.
So it will get provided field `name` from the `record`.
And since you've called `name` by yourself, it returns the actual value of the name instead of the whole object `record` and then tries to get name from that value which results in this error.

So you need to change that line to `<td><%= best_in_place record, :name %></td>`.

Comment: Yes, i have check this also, it's work, using this , how can i display db value, it can't displayed using only `record` object.

Comment: I need display value like `record.name` which fetched value from db and need to edit that value in table.

Comment: How I can get options value from db like `<td><%= best_in_place record, :gender, type: :select, collection: MGender.all.map{ |i| [i.gender, i.id] }, include_blank: 'selcect option' %></td>`  it's not working properly

Comment: Looks like there is a mistake in this code. The docs say you need to use `as: :select` instead of `type: :select`.

Comment: `<% @user.each do |record| %>
  <td><%= best_in_place record, :gender, :as => :select, :collection =>  (MUser.all.map{ |i| 
    [i.id, i.gender]}) %></td>
<% end %>`    I am trying to display select fields option data, but it didn't shows, displayed by default data like `-` how can i display current values with all options data.

Comment: @vvp45 not sure why this could happen, need to debug it. 
Just in case - are you sure there are some values present in `MUser` model?

Also, to improve performance you can do `MUser.pluck(:id, :gender)` instead of `MUser.all.map{ |i|      [i.id, i.gender]}`.

Comment: getting stucked in that more than one day, didn't understand what's problem? and also having issue with date, `<td><%= best_in_place record, :dob, :as => :input, class:'datepicker' %></td>` didn't changed date, also used `datepicker` gem.

Comment: for date type check these links from docs: 

1) https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#rails

2) https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#date

Comment: Tried with this also and code was like `<td><%= best_in_place record, :dob, :as => :date, class:'datepicker1' %></td>`  didn't changed, if changed month then it's setting start year and month like `year 1923 and month Jan`

Comment: Did you check the link I've sent you above about configuring DatePicker defaults?
`With the :date type the input field will be initialized as a datepicker input. In order to provide custom options to the datepicker initialization you must prepare a $.datepicker.setDefaults call with the preferences of your choice.

More information about datepicker and setting defaults can be found here`

There was a link to DatePicker docs, you need to configure it to make it working correctly - https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: yes, i have done it before also, and configured like            
`$('.datepicker1').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', regional: "en",todayHighlight: true,
changeMonth: true, todayHighlight: true, language: "en", orientation: "auto",
toggleActive: true, autoclose: true });` it's work in other page also.